# HTML Anchor ID not working

Tags: html, anchor

I'm making a quick site and all the content is on one page, and I'm using a small menu with anchor links to make navigating to a certain part faster for the end user. I have two anchor links that work fine (About Me, My Projects) but the "Contact Me" link jumps to a random part of the "My Projects" section.

A preview of the site is available here : http://dev.cuonic.com/cuonic.com/

I have checked the IDs, they correspond, there is no random "contact-me" ID lying around in the "My Projects" section, I've changed the ID, still happens, and this in both Firefox and Chrome. Whats going on ? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Some HTML syntax error is closing the `<span id="contact-me">` immediately. Hence the issue

Comment: Your contact-me link is trying to find an anchor that's not there. Have you tried placing an anchor above your contact form?

Comment: The anchor is there, I've checked and double checked that. It was a CSS problem.

Comment: @karthikr : It's not a syntax error, it's a fix for the fixed header and anchor problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of then content within `//*[@id="content"]/div[2]` is floated to the left. Floating elements don't affect the height of their containing block-level elements. If you add this:

`#contact-me { clear:both; }`

to your CSS somewhere, the `<span id="contact-me">` tag will reposition to where you actually want it. Your page still isn't long enough for the contact form to go all the way to the top (at least on my monitor), but it will still scroll to the end of the page.

Comment: I added the clear both to the .anchor class instead, but it worked perfectly, thanks :) I didn't know that an anchor problem could be related to the floats, and no the page isn't long enough, but that's not a problem.

Comment: @Cuonic Shameless request to "accept" the answer by clicking the green arrow?

Comment: Yeah, I just had to wait 5 minutes to accept the answer for some reason. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this section of code:

```
</div>
<span class="anchor" id="contact-me"></span>
<h1>Contact Me</h1>
<div class="text">
```

To this:

```
</div>
<h1>Contact Me</h1>
<span class="anchor" id="contact-me"></span>
<div class="text">
```

Comment: That defeats the goal of the span, it is there to fix an anchor problem and the other two work fine, but the problem is solved now, it was to do with CSS floats.

Comment: @Cuonic Yes, the clear:both is much better. Please mark Ben Harold's answer as correct. Thanks.